# How many displays can a Mac Mini 2014 drive

Tags: mac-mini

How many displays can a Mac Mini 2014 drive?

Given that the Mac Mini now has 2 thunderbolt + 1 HDMI video outputs, it would be able to drive 3 monitors right? It ofcourse depends on the resolutions. Not sure what that Intel Iris Graphics card can take.

Comment: Is it 100% confirmed that 3 displays is a no-go on the 2014 Mini when using 1 HDMI, and both Thunderbolt ports?

Comment: As of April 2015 - Yes, this is a NO-GO. Any combination of 2 displays work, but not 3 at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried it with 3 displays, but no go.  Any combination of 2 displays work, but not 3 at the same time.

Comment: I can confirm this.  Bought a top-of-the-spec i7, 16G mem, 2TB HD and any combination of 2 displays work, but not 3 at the same time.  Called Apple support and they just pointed me to the spec page where is says "supports up to 2 monitors".  Mentioned about Intel Iris spec supporting 3 and they said I should log a feature request on the their feedback page.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/hd-graphics/hd-graphics-developer.html

A section in the webpage listed above states:

"View movies or presentations in ultra-high definition on Ultra HDTV or 4K resolution displays. With Intel Iris and Intel HD graphics, you can even daisy-chain up to three displays—or use collage mode to combine displays into a single unified higher resolution for larger screen sizes."

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!. Not sure why Apple says upto 2 displays - http://www.apple.com/mac-mini/specs/ . Maybe its that resolution. Its not really clear.