# Hook up 3 monitors to Mac Mini Late 2014

Tags: mac-mini, thunderbolt

I have the Mac Mini late 2014 and want to hook up 3 monitors in total.
It works great with 2 displays (1x Thunderbolt + 1x HDMI). Once I add a third monitor to the second Thunderbolt port, just nothing happens. What can I do to get my third monitor working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Apple's specs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154#18) show that the late-2014 (which is still being sold today, October 2015) Mac Mini can support up to **two displays** using its HDMI and thunderbolt ports.
I've confirmed this by trying to plug in 3 monitors directly into the ports on the Mac Mini (two via thunderbolt, 1 via HDMI), with the same results as the OP...one of the monitors is not driven.

### The following 3-monitor setup worked for me:

- Late 2014 Mac Mini with 8GB RAM (purchased Oct 2015)
- 3 monitors, each with 1920x1200 resolution
- Monitor 1: driven by Mac mini HDMI port (HDMI-to-HDMI cable)
- Monitor 2: driven by Mac Mini thunderbolt port (I used [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DJCB83O) thunderbolt-to-DVI cable)
- Monitor 3: driven via USB 3.0 adapter (I used [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BPEV1XK) from CableMatters and have had zero issues with flicker/performance, although I am not trying to play games or watch video on it...I use it for work).

---

Some notes:

- You can use a different USB adapter (there are several on the market) but make sure that it's Mac compatible.  I previously tried one that had "beta" Mac support and it was terrible.
- Thunderbolt-to-HDMI and Thunderbolt-to-DVI cables are really mini-displayport to DVI/HDMI cables....the Thunderbolt ports accept mini-displayport connectors.
- For the two natively driven monitors (#1 and #2 above) you can use any combination of HDMI<->HDMI/DVI or thunderbolt<->HDMI/DVI cables depending on what your monitor accepts.

Comment: Has anyone done this as well to confirm it works ?

Answer (score 3):

[This article](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150885/how-many-displays-can-a-mac-mini-2014-drive) might contain information on why this doesn't work.

First off, you're talking about a low-end machine which utilizes shared system memory for its graphics.  I drive two Thunderbolt displays with my 2012 Mac Mini with 16GB of RAM and an SSD.  The Mini uses a static amount of RAM for video, it does not adjust based on how much RAM is in the machine.  As an aside, this is a good reason to max out the RAM on a machine with shared video.

You have a machine with shared video RAM totaling 1 GB, and you're trying to drive two 1440p displays and one 1080p display, a total of 5.76 MP of video output.  It's worth noting, the iMac 5K is driving *less* pixels, and it requires a 2 GB dedicated video card.

Answer (score 1):

You can do 1x hdmi
1x hdmi to mini display
And 1x hdmi to hdmi-usb dongle

The Mac mini only supports two monitors unless you mess with the graphics, so using the usb dongle tricks it. Warning (eats ram)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: https://www.i-tech.com.au/products/146188_Wavlink_WL_UG35D6_USB_3_0_to_DVI.aspx

Note: in my experience, the more additional USB devices you have plugged in, the more likely your 3rd monitor is likely to not work (flicks on and off) due to, I assume, lack of power.

Comment: Broken link :-P

Answer (score 1):

I use a thunderbolt 2 docking station which allows me to add 1 hdmi port and an additional thunderbolt port to add 2 monitors